# Pick correct function signature from object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a simple editor. Currently the code looks like (relevant pieces only):

```js
class Editor {
  private project: Project;

  private handlers = {
    // those will do something more meaningful
    'add-table': (project: Project, details: { name: string }) => project,
    'remove-table': (project: Project, details: { uuid: string }) => project,
  }

  dispatch(action: { name: string, details: any }) {
    this.project = this.handlers[action.name](this.project, action.details);
  }
}
```

Now I'd like to add type safety. So when I add a table, I have to call

```js
editor.dispatch({ name: 'add-table', details: { name: 'MyNewTable' } })
```

So far the closest I could get was:

```js
dispatch<
  N extends keyof Editor['handlers'],
  D extends Parameters<Editor['handlers'][N]>[1]
>(
  action: { name: N, details: D }
) {
  // function body...
}
```

(if N is a key of handlers, then D is the type of second argument of a function that's stored in handlers under the key N).

How do I type this thing properly?
If I can achieve type safety in a different way, I will accept such answer as well.

Comment: What's exactly problem with your solution?

Comment: Argument of type 'D' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; } & { uuid: string; }'.
One of the reasons is:
Type '{ name: string; } | { uuid: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; } & { uuid: string; }'.

Comment: And that error is happening... where?  I can guess it's in the implementation, and you're probably just going to want to use a type assertion and move on, as these sort of ["correlated" values, microsoft/TypeScript#30851](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) are not really well-supported

Comment: this was in the implementation. First line of dispatch was just `const result = this.handlers[action.name](this.project, action.details)`. "details" was highlighted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two sides of `dispatch()`... the call signature, seen by the caller, and the implementation, not seen by the caller.  Your proposed solution should mostly work for the caller, right?  It prevents callers from (easily) passing the wrong parameters.

But inside the implementation, it doesn't "work".  This is a known limitation of TypeScript.  The compiler does not maintain the *correlation* between `action.name` and `action.details` when it comes time to call the function.  It (correctly) interprets `this.handlers[action.name]` as (a subtype of) a union of function types.  It also (correctly) interprets `action.details` as (a subtype of) a union of parameter types to those functions.  Unfortunately, it treats these unions as independent of each other, which they are not.  The compiler is unnecessarily concerned that perhaps `action.name` will be from one handler and `action.details` will be from another.  And there's no great way to fix this.

I've opened an issue about this, [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), but mostly just as a way to make a note this limitation.  I don't see any fix on the horizon; a naive "keep track of everything" approach would not be scalable.  I had made a suggestion to allow developers to ask for extra control flow analysis in certain scopes ([microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051)), but that would be too complicated for developers to use.

For now, you have to work around it.  You *could* write redundant code that walks through each possibility manually.  But the easiest workaround is just to use a type assertion to tell the compiler to stop worrying:

```
this.project = this.handlers[action.name](this.project, action.details as any);
```

This is what I usually do; you can tailor your type assertion to be less unsafe than `any`, such as the intersection mentioned in the error message, but I rarely find that to be worth the effort.

---

As an aside, your call signature doesn't need to be generic to be safe from the caller's side.  You could calculate the type of `action` as a union, like this:

```
type Handlers = Editor['handlers']
type Action = { [K in keyof Handlers]: { name: K, details: Parameters<Handlers[K]>[1] } }[keyof Handlers];
```

And then `dispatch` would just take an `Action`:

```
  dispatch(action: Action) {
    this.project = this.handlers[action.name](this.project, action.details as any);
  }
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYCsILMgbwChlkAHTHPALmQGcwpQBzAbiIF8iiwBPMlAAk4IACYAbaHWQBeZAFFRwMBigBtAOQALERKkaAuj34oAgnmAYQswsjUBpZKGQBrCLwwxkwsZKh0DWgJkEDgAWwhaewAaZFEIMDhgcTpaVDgocISpAB4fPX8HAwA+NQBGA2QOKrUSV3dPb10-APYiBHE4OmlFZVVCOopgADc4SHJKXDAAQjTJvDbSIdHxnV8pG2JSUg04UVEAWkSAI0kNWgAKCmwpuZu8WPjE5NTbUIjaBiYQZiqASlkxQm9zA0TqOygEDCGGGECOcFOEHOyCu8zAdyooLiCSSKSCyAArgTgKJPowWP9AcDMWDSFw6ko6GQxggtBdEGBLCBaOZOVYAVttmAtMA6AA6a6YmzC0VitYFOhqDlcsXvCAGC4y8WSqaxZVWMVPXHSLrIES8P7sOncDhAA)

Comment: Could you provide a little more info, or a link, to this syntax? `type Action = { [K in keyof Handlers]: { name: K, details: Parameters<Handlers[K]>[1] } }[
  keyof Editor['handlers']];` The `[keyof Editor['handlers']]` part specifically. What is it doing, is it turning an object into union of it's values? Is that a good way to read that?

Comment: I should have just written `[keyof Handlers]` since I defined `type Handlers = Editor['handlers']`... edited that above.

Comment: Now, for your question: the `{[K in keyof Handlers]: {name: K, details: ...}}` part is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).  And if you have an object type `T` and a key `K` of that type (or union of keys) then `T[K]` [looks up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the property types (or union of property types) at that key.  Combining those two takes a keylike union (`keyof Handlers`), maps it to an object and then gets the union of its value types.

Comment: If I have a union of keys `KS` and a type function `F<>` to apply to each of those keys you can use this syntax to distribute `F` over the union `KS`: `{[K in KS]: F<K>}[KS]`.  You can also do that with [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) but it's a bit more cumbersome.