# How to write typeguard for array of discriminated union types?

Tags: typescript

Minimal code reproduction of what I want to do:

```
const handlers = {
  foo: (s: string) => s.length,
  bar: (n: number) => n.toFixed(2)
}

type DataMap = {
  [P in keyof typeof handlers]: {
    type: P,
    data: Parameters<typeof handlers[P]>[0]
  }
}

type Block = DataMap[keyof DataMap];

const data: Array<Block> = []

data.forEach(block => {
  if (block.type in handlers) {
    // Error: Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
    handlers[block.type](block.data)
  }
})
```

Right now there is an error inside forEach `Error: Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

How should I write typeguard for such case?

EDIT:

If there is no solution right now except for assertion then maybe there is a better way to structure such data?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Pick correct function signature from object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343438/pick-correct-function-signature-from-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is yet another instance of what I've been calling "correlated record types", which the TypeScript compiler can't reason about very well.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for details, but the issue is that the compiler sees that `block.type` and `block.data` are each of a union of types, but it does not understand that only some of the possibilities can happen at the same time while others are not.  If you walk the compiler through the cases, it is fine:

```
data.forEach(block => {
    if (block.type in handlers) {
        if (block.type === "foo") {
            handlers[block.type](block.data)
        } else {
            handlers[block.type](block.data)
        }
    }
})
```

since in each case it can narrow `block` to one of the members of a discriminated union.  But it can't reason about it in general.  You should probably just use a type assertion and move on, like maybe:

```
data.forEach(block => {
    (handlers[block.type] as (args: Block['data']) => any)(block.data)
})
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#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)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to rewrite this because the `Block` type seemed to be defined the wrong way around; what i ended up with is:

```
interface Block<P extends keyof typeof handlers>
{
    type: P,
    data: Parameters<typeof handlers[P]>[0]
}

const data: Array<Block> = []
```

And now you get to the root of the problem on the last line which raises the error:

> Generic type `Block<P>` requires 1 type argument(s). ts(2314)

The type only makes any sense if it has a generic argument that ties the properties `type` and `data` logically together. So as soon as you to try make that an array, this becomes impossible.

You might have to either restructure your objects or ignore the type errors.

Comment: `Block` in the original example is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions), a very common data structure in TypeScript.  Why would it be "the wrong way around", and how does making it generic address anything?  Note that even in your version, you could have `data: Array<Block<"foo"> | Block<"bar">>`, which restores the discriminated union.

Comment: Yes, I also not quite understand. `Block<keyof typeof handlers>` in your example would generate basically same union as in my version.

Comment: @jcalz: I am aware of the fact that it is a discriminating union, i use them all the time. It is defined the wrong way around because the `DataMap` was only used to pull out the type of its properties and the properties are not defined in the map itself but another object, so you might as well skip the map entirely. The generic is simply necessary because `data` is dependent on `type`. Of course you can enumerate all the possible values but that takes away most of the convenience of having an array to iterate over.

Comment: @Danila: And it also would lose all the information you would need to generically handle each block.

Comment: What I mean, it does not matter how you generate this union, with map, or with your way, or hardcode all the options manually. The end result is the same and the question was how could you work with such structure to avoid `any`. Thank you for your example though, it might be easier to write it that way.